# Help with htaccess querystring rewrite

Tags: htaccess

Been working on a solution to remove odd query strings from pages after search engines keep adding them at random. I have a solution that semi works, but I would ideally like to see it clear them all. Right now the code I have is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?sort=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?order=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?m=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&itemid[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am very open to suggestion to clean things up and make a much more optimized solution.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to explain what it is you are trying to do exactly. (And why this is not working as intended.) However, this is likely just masking an underlying problem... why are search engines indexing these URLs in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to remove the query strings with m=7291 or itemid etc. And currently it gets rid of some of the strings, but if the URL has many it only will manage to remove one. And It seems something how google indexed the pages, I have tried to remove them, but since there are links from other sites that include the string to our site, people still seem to come to the links.